# Using custom UISlider subclass to change appearance of MPVolumeView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a subclass of `UISlider` called `VolumeSlider`, with the intent being to just increase the thickness of the track and reduce the size of the thumb (similar to the appearance of the default volume view in the music player). I don't want to use custom images, as the default iOS 7 slider has the basic appearance I want. In my subclass, I'm overriding the following 2 methods in order to achieve this:

```
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value
```

My question is: How can I apply this `UISlider` subclass to my `MPVolumeView`?

Comment: Actually I just saw that MPVolumeView has similar methods I can override: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPVolumeView/volumeSliderRectForBounds:

Comment: After subclassing MPVolumeView instead, it doesn't actually increase the thickness of the track or change the size of the thumb when overriding those methods. Guess I may have to use custom images.